# How to trigger a reload of PFTableViewController using Parse with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I've got a PFTableViewController that displays a table of items. I then segue to a navigation controller with root view controller that allows the user to enter a new item - and after they press save, I dismiss the view controller and return to the PFTableViewController.

I would like to reload the PFTableViewController at this point - so that its list includes the item that the user just added. Currently my attempts to get it to reload are not working; the user has to pull to refresh which is broken - it feels like the added item was not properly saved because it doesn't automatically show up.

I've put the self.tableView.reloadData() in the viewDidLoad() function - and it clearly fires as I added a println to verify that it triggers when the new item view is dismissed. But the table is not reloading the data.

Here's 1 version of the code that I've tried:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    println("going to reload")

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And another, based on another example I saw:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    println("going to reload")

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Neither are working.

Here's the majority of the PFTableViewController file set-up in case it's useful as well:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class CategoryViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {
    var currentObject : PFObject?
    var candidates: Array<AnyObject>?

    override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, className: className)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.parseClassName = "CategoryCandidates"
        self.textKey = "candidateTitle"
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.paginationEnabled = false
    }

    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
        var query = PFQuery(className: "CategoryCandidates")
        query.whereKey("categoryID", equalTo: currentObject!)
        query.orderByDescending("votes")
        return query
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> CandidateTableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CandidateTableViewCell!
        if cell == nil {
            cell = CandidateTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }

        cell?.voteButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


        // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
        if let candidateTitle = object?["candidateTitle"] as? String {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = candidateTitle
        }

        if let votesTotal = object?["votes"] as? Int {
            if votesTotal > 1 {
                cell?.votesLabel.text = "\(votesTotal.description) votes"
            } else if votesTotal == 1 {
                cell?.votesLabel.text = "\(votesTotal.description) vote"
            }
        }

        cell.voteButton.tag = indexPath.row

        return cell
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `[self loadObjects]`  and that's one among many reasons to use parse's convenience class only for learning, then write your own as soon as you can.  (That goes for UITableViewController, too.  Once you work out how to use a UIViewController with a tableView, you won't want to go back.)

Comment: Wow, that worked! Do you want to put it in an answer so that I can give you credit? Also, what do you mean by a convenience class - do you mean PFTableViewController and the rest of Parse's native classes?

Comment: Thanks. Added an answer to help the next reader. My point about the parse UI classes only is that they're helpful before you understand how they work. Once you do, I find they get in the way more than help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PFQueryTable vc must do two things to refresh the data: (1) rerun the query, and (2) after the query has run, reload the table view. The method `loadObjects` runs the query, and the query's completion handler reloads the table view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a delegate to notify the PFTableViewController

```
protocol CategoryViewControllerDelegate {
    func reloadTable()
}

class CategoryViewController: PFQueryTableViewController, CategoryViewControllerDelegate {

//  MARK: CategoryViewControllerDelegate
    func reloadTable() {
        self.tableView.reloadTable()
    }

    // method to segue into adding of new item
    fund addNewItem() {
        let view = NewItemViewController()
        view.delegate = self
        presentViewController(view, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class NewItemViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate:CategoryViewControllerDelegate?

    func handleAddNewItem() {
        // handle the adding of new item here
        // ...

        // then call the delegate to reload the table
        delegate.reloadTable()

        // dismiss and return to parent view
        // ... 
    }
}
```